# JavaFX Threads Atualizar UI e carregar Sistema em segundo plano

Tags: java, concorrência, javafx

Tenho um `Stage` Principal que é o meu Login:

[image: SS]

No `FXML` desse stage tenho uma `Region` e uma `ProgressIndicator` com a propriedade `setVisible(false)`

Após logar com sucesso no aplicação a intenção seria exibir essa `Region` e a `ProgressIndicator` enquanto uma *thread* iniciava a aplicação, mas o que acontece é que após logar a *thread* começa a rodar carregando a aplicação, mas a `Region` e a `ProgressIndicator`, não ficam visíveis.

#### Minha *thread*

```
 Task t = new Task() {
    
    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {
        
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {
                
                new SisgeFX().start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
};
region.visibleProperty().bind(t.runningProperty());
pi.visibleProperty().bind(t.runningProperty());
Thread th = new Thread(t);
th.start();
```

Tentei fazendo duas *threads*: uma para carregar o sistema e outra para atualizar
o `ProgressIndicator` enquanto o sistema não é carregado, mas sem sucesso,
não gera `Exception`, já tentei de diversas maneiras.

#### O que percebi nas minhas diversas tentativas:

1. Uma *Thread* é iniciada e a outra não (Inicia apenas a Thread que carrega o sistema).
2. A *Thread* não inicia.
3. A *Thread* inicia mas a `ProgressIndicator` fica travada, não fica animada.

#### Trecho do login:

```
@FXML
private void sysLogin() {
    String user = ctfUserLogin.getText();
    String pass = ctfPassLogin.getText();
    LoginDAO loginDAO = DAOFactory.make(LoginDAO.class);
    Login login = loginDAO.getLogin(user, pass);
    
    if (login != null) {
        runThread(); // aqui chamo a Thread postado acima.
        ctfPassLogin.setStyle(null);
        ctfUserLogin.setStyle(null);
    } else {
        ctfPassLogin.clear();
        ctfUserLogin.clear();
        ctfPassLogin.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        ctfUserLogin.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        //new ShakeTransition(vBox).play();
        new WobbleTransition(vBox).play();
        //new TadaTransition(vBox).play();
    }
}
```

Após *login* com sucesso como exibir a `ProgressIndicartor` enquanto o sistema é carregado em segundo plano?

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira elegante de resolver seu problema é a criação de um Preloader, considerada uma [boa prática de programação](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm) no JavaFX. O Preloader é especialmente útil para melhorar a experiência do usuário quando ele precisa esperar a conclusão de operações pesadas antes do início da aplicação. Inclusive há uma maneira de fazer um Login Preloader, explicado com detalhes [neste tutorial da Oracle - Seção 9.3.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABIJCII).

Entretanto, nos exemplos citados, o carregamento é feito antes o durante do login e não depois. (Talvez exista um workaround para conseguir este efeito)

(NetBeans) Criando um Prealoder:

1. Crie um Preloader em New Project > JavaFX > JavaFX Preloader;
2. Clique com o botão direito no projeto vá em Properties (Propriedades) > Run > Marque "Use Preloader" > Clique em "Browse" > "Choose Preloader from Project" > Selecione a pasta do seu Preloader;
3. Crie o método public void init() na sua aplicação principal.

Dentro do método init() você pode todo o carregamento imprescindível para sua aplicação, pontuando o progresso através do método `notifyPreloader(new ProgressNotification(0.10)) // Para 10%;`

Eis um exemplo de preloader com uma simples barra de progresso:

```
public class AppPreloader extends Preloader{

private Stage stage;
private ProgressBar bar;
private boolean noLoadingProgress = true;

private Scene createPreloaderScene() {
    bar = new ProgressBar();

    VBox vb = new VBox();
    vb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    bar.setPrefWidth(150);
    vb.getChildren().addAll(bar);

    return new Scene(vb, 300, 150);        
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage){  
    this.stage = stage;
    stage.setScene(createPreloaderScene());        
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void handleStateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification scn) {

}

@Override
public void handleProgressNotification(ProgressNotification pn) {
    //application loading progress is rescaled to be first 50%
    //Even if there is nothing to load 0% and 100% events can be
    // delivered
    if (pn.getProgress() != 1.0 || !noLoadingProgress) {
      bar.setProgress(pn.getProgress()/2);
      if (pn.getProgress() > 0) {
          noLoadingProgress = false;
      }
    }
}

@Override
public void handleApplicationNotification(PreloaderNotification pn) {
    if (pn instanceof ProgressNotification) {
       //expect application to send us progress notifications 
       //with progress ranging from 0 to 1.0
       double v = ((ProgressNotification) pn).getProgress();
       if (!noLoadingProgress) {
           //if we were receiving loading progress notifications 
           //then progress is already at 50%. 
           //Rescale application progress to start from 50%               
           v = 0.5 + v/2;
       }
       bar.setProgress(v);            
    } else if (pn instanceof StateChangeNotification) {
        //hide after get any state update from application
        stage.hide();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vi isso no seu código:

```
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
```

Essa linha que vai fazer  o progressbar rodar.